# Local databases in Windows 8, post-release

Tags: sql, database, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

Now that windows 8 has been released, I am under the impression that a greater variety of ways for developers to use local databases in metro apps is now available to us (SQL Express LocalDB?). Up until now I have using the SQLite3 version that runs on windows 8, but know that I can I want to try and use the database features built in to Visual Studio 2012 (Won't this be better?)

To do this I am trying to follow the documentation on MSDN (here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763) however when I go to Project > Add New Item, I don't have a "Service-Based Database" option. What am I missing? Is there another component I need to install, or do I have it all completely wrong? I haven't used any of the sample databases mention in the documentation because I wanted to add it straight into my app. I'm using VS2012 Pro.

Comment: I think Microsoft is pushing SkyDrive for Store Apps.

Comment: If that is the case, I would think it would be unreasonable to have my app upload a database to the users SkyDrive each time a change was made? I guess I may just have to stick to SQLite and local storage for now

Comment: Well, you wouldn't be storing the entire database in SkyDrive, but instead using SkyDrive as the storage location for the user's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 8 app store api does not have any built-in database capabilities.  Microsoft really wants you to use cloud storage.  The documentation you're trying to follow is for windows 8 desktop applications *not* windows 8 store applications.  You're probably best off using sqlite for the foreseeable future.